# How to load swf file to QWebEngineView from memory

Tags: python, flash, pyqt5, qtwebengine

i am trying to load flash (swf) file using QWebEngineView
i want to load the swf from memory but i was only able to load it from a URL so far

data is a bytearray of the result of urlopen (urllib).
`self.webview` is an instance of QWebEngineView.

```py
self.webview.load(QtCore.QUrl(url))              # works
self.webview.setContent(QtCore.QByteArray(data)) # does not work
```

using a URL the swf runs. loading from the bytearray results in empty page or page with gibberish. no errors are showing.

i am using pyqt5 with python3

Comment: Why did you delete your answer? What url are you referring to in your question?

Comment: @eyllanesc i didn't notice that i forgot to remove the old load function, it didnt work, it only loaded using load after it failed using setContent. it works with any external url, tried a few different sites. url is a string here.

Comment: Could you provide me with one of those "urls" that you used for your test

Comment: @eyllanesc yes, one of the links i used "https://condor.depaul.edu/sjost/hci430/flash-examples/swf/wheel.swf"

Comment: One more question: what version of pyqt5 do you use and what is your OS?

Comment: @eyllanesc python 3.8.5 with pyqt5 5.15. Running it on linux (arch) with kernel 5.8.3 (x64)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you cannot pass the raw-data directly so a workaround is to create a custom QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler that provides the resource through a url:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineCore, QtWebEngineWidgets


class CustomUrlSchemeHandler(QtWebEngineCore.QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler):
    SCHEMENAME = b"custom"

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._datas = dict()

    def add_data(self, path, mimetype, data):
        self._datas[path] = mimetype, data
        url = QtCore.QUrl()
        url.setScheme(self.SCHEMENAME.decode())
        url.setPath(path)
        return url

    def requestStarted(self, job):
        requestMethod = job.requestMethod()
        if requestMethod != b"GET":
            job.fail(QtWebEngineCore.QWebEngineUrlRequestJob.RequestDenied)
            return

        requestUrl = job.requestUrl()
        requestPath = requestUrl.path()
        value = self._datas.get(requestPath)
        if value is not None:
            mimetype, data = value
            buf = QtCore.QBuffer(parent=self)
            job.destroyed.connect(buf.deleteLater)
            buf.open(QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
            buf.write(data)
            buf.close()
            job.reply(mimetype.encode(), buf)
        else:
            job.fail(QtWebEngineCore.QWebEngineUrlRequestJobUrlNotFound)

    @classmethod
    def registerUrlScheme(cls):
        scheme = QtWebEngineCore.QWebEngineUrlScheme(cls.SCHEMENAME)
        QtWebEngineCore.QWebEngineUrlScheme.registerScheme(scheme)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys
    import urllib.request

    data = b""
    with urllib.request.urlopen(
        "https://condor.depaul.edu/sjost/hci430/flash-examples/swf/wheel.swf"
    ) as response:
        data = response.read()

    CustomUrlSchemeHandler.registerUrlScheme()

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    settings = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.defaultSettings()
    settings.setAttribute(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)

    view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()

    handler = CustomUrlSchemeHandler()
    view.page().profile().installUrlSchemeHandler(handler.SCHEMENAME, handler)

    view.resize(640, 480)
    view.show()

    url = handler.add_data("test.swg", "application/x-shockwave-flash", data)
    view.load(url)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help, this workaround works great! im now able to load flash files in my qt gui and from memory and change between flash files quickly and without network usage (once cached)